# How to update objects in WCF

Tags: c#, forms, wcf

I am kind of new with WCF. I have been using .Net Remoting for so long. So I am trying a bit the reason is because Net Remoting isn't longer supported in other environments.

For now I have this problem: First I didn't know how to set the behavior that some I got reading from here an Microsoft to set the InstanceContextMode, that's resolved.
Second for now I don't know how Set an object that automatically update. Let me explain better. In .NET Remoting if I set an array any change in this one from the server side it will auto update his values. So the clients will get the last update.

Sorry If you can't understand. I tried my best.
Thank in Advance.

Comment: You are moving from an ancient technology to a very old one. Are you sure you don't want to learn gRPC or REST?

Comment: anything possible only if is compatible with winforms or wpf.

Comment: Everything is compatible with WinForms and WPF. They are just applications that can use any other library

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found myself with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my case WCF is perfect because the libraries I used are licensed and are attached to an old version of .NET winform so if we want to pass data to a .Net Core Worker Service using WCF is the correct solution.

Answering my question I was reading a lot and I found myself realizing that setting early the objects it will dynamically update if they change.

```
        WCF_Service.WCF_Values wCF = new WCF_Service.WCF_Values();
        wCF.Set_StringArray(string1_predefined_object);
```

after that just initialize the ServiceHost and any changes directly in the string1_predefined_object will auto update when we get the whole Array through a Client.

if you want to keep yours object in all incoming calls just define the behavior before the non interface class as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```